# Django 1.11.5 templates in nested folders

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I have a problem with Django Templates in nested folders.
My project has the next schema:

```
 .
    ├── eventus
    │   ├── eventus
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── db.sqlite3
    │   │   ├── settings
    │   │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   │   │   ├── base.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   │   │   └── local.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   │   ├── base.py
    │   │   │   ├── local.py
    │   │   │   ├── prod.py
    │   │   │   └── staging.py
    │   │   ├── urls.py
    │   │   └── wsgi.py
    │   ├── manage.py
    │   └── myapps
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── __pycache__
    │       │   └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │       ├── events
    │       │   ├── __init__.py
    │       │   ├── __pycache__
    │       │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │       │   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
    │       │   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
    │       │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
    │       │   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
    │       │   ├── admin.py
    │       │   ├── apps.py
    │       │   ├── migrations
    │       │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │       │   │   ├── 0002_auto_20170924_2140.py
    │       │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │       │   │   └── __pycache__
    │       │   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
    │       │   │       ├── 0002_auto_20170924_2115.cpython-36.pyc
    │       │   │       ├── 0002_auto_20170924_2140.cpython-36.pyc
    │       │   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │       │   ├── models.py
    │       │   ├── templates
    │       │   │   ├── base.html
    │       │   │   └── events
    │       │   │       ├── base_events.html
    │       │   │       └── index.html
    │       │   ├── tests.py
    │       │   ├── urls.py
    │       │   └── views.py
    │       └── users
    │           ├── __init__.py
    │           ├── __pycache__
    │           │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │           │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
    │           │   └── models.cpython-36.pyc
    │           ├── admin.py
    │           ├── apps.py
    │           ├── migrations
    │           │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │           │   ├── __init__.py
    │           │   └── __pycache__
    │           │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
    │           │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │           ├── models.py
    │           ├── tests.py
    │           └── views.py
    └── requirements
        ├── base.txt
        ├── local.txt
        ├── prod.txt
        └── staging.txt
```

And my `templates/base.html` is :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

and my `templates/events/base.html` is

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

and mi `templates/events/index.html` is

```
    {% extends "events/base_events.html" %}

{% block title %}Home{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Eventus</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li><a href="{% url 'events_app:panel' %}">Hola {{ user.username|capfirst }}</a></li>
                {% else %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'events_app:panel' %}">Sign Up / Login</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <h1>EVENTUS</h1>
    <p>Bienvenido a EVENTUS, aquí podrás encontrar eventos que se den en tu ciudad e inscribirte on-line con un solo click.</p>
    <p>¡<a href="{% url 'users_app:login' %}" role="button">Registrate</a> y crea tu evento ahora!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

    <div class="page-header">
        <h4><strong>Eventos disponibles</strong></h4>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span></span>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>Categoría</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></span></span>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Tipo pago</option>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Busca el evento de tu gusto">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<p></p>

<div class="container eventos">    

    <div class="row contenedor-eventos">
        {% for event in events %}
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-3 ">
            <div class="thumbnail equal">
                <img src="{{ event.imagen.url }}" alt="250x180">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4><a href="">{{ event.name }}</a></h4>
                    <small class="date">{{ event.start }}</small>
                    <div class="place">
                        <small class="place">{{ event.place}}</small> / 
                    </div>
                    <span class="views">{{ event.views }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>

</div>

<div class="container categorias">    

    <div class="page-header">
        <h4><strong>Categorías relacionadas</strong></h4>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-12">
        {% for category in categories %}
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-fix">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> {{ category.name }}
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="container organizadores">    

    <div class="page-header">
        <h4><strong>Organizadores destacados</strong></h4>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x180" alt="250x180">
                <div class="caption">
                    Nombre organizador
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

my `view.py` is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Event, Category
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    events = Event.objects.all().order_by('-created')[:6]
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'events': events, 'categories': categories})
```

my `url.py` is

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('myapp.events.views.index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and my `base.py` in templates I have this configuration

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/templates', '/templates/events'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

And the error of my page is the next:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
index.html
Exception Location: /Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in get_template, line 25
Python Executable:  /Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/CursoProDjango/eventus',
 '/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/dmuino/anaconda/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 25 Sep 2017 11:33:20 +0000
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /templates/events/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/dmuino/.virtualenvs/Pruebas/CursoProDjango/eventus/myapps/events/templates/index.html (Source does not exist)
```

How can I do that Django read the subdirectories in template folder with the different archives html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view should be rendering `events/index.html`.

**Edit** Actually the problem is in your template settings. The `DIRS` value should be a list of *absolute* paths. You need to prepend the value of BASE_DIR to give the full path.

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

Note you should not be including 'events' in that list at all. As I said originally, render "events/index.html"; otherwise you'll start getting very confused about what templates are in which directory.

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I do it, but now the error is:
'NoReverseMatch at /
'events_app' is not a registered namespace
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
'events_app' is not a registered namespace'

Comment: Well that is a completely separate question, and one that has been answered many many times before here.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why I need put events/index.html in my view, when I call the directory in my base in template dirs 
'DIRS': ['/templates', '/templates/events'],

Comment: Thanks, for your help.
That is exercise I think there is a difficult issue because the /template/events/index.html call to /template/events/base_template.html and this call template/base.html, that it is in other folder.

Comment: But that's the standard structure: events/index.html extends events/base_template.html which in turn extends base.html. What problems are you having with that?

Comment: I put this questions for my second problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46407854/noreversematch-at-with-templates-in-different-folders